# How can CCKeyDerivationPBKDF be converted to Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, cryptography, pkcs#5

I have the ObjC method below and I'd like to call do port it to managed code but have no idea where to start. Can somebody please assist?

```
- (NSData *)deriveKey
{
    NSData *passphrase = [self.passwordField.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *salt = [self.saltField.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kCCKeySizeAES256];
    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2,
                         [passphrase bytes],
                         [passphrase length],
                         [salt bytes],
                         [salt length],
                         kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256,
                         PBKDFNumberOfRounds,
                         [key mutableBytes],
                         [key length]);
    return key;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET PKCS#5v2 (which defines **PBKDF2**) support is available using [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx). However it does not let you select the hash algorithm.

```
var salt = new byte [32]; // do not use it empty :)
var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes ("passphrase", salt, 1000).GetBytes (length);
```

Comment: I know that one. Forgot to mention it. It is using SHA1 according to the documentation, so it's of no help. Any chance I can invoke the native method?

Comment: `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF` is a **C** API, you'll need to p/invoke it. The alternative is copy/pasting Mono's `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` source code and adapting it to use any `HashAlgorithm` (or hardcode yours to `SHA256`). Former is easier, later is more useful for cross-platform support.

Comment: And the outcome of the managed key is the same as of the native?

Comment: Yes. PKCS#5 is a standard - so with the same input data then you'll get the same output (key) across implementations. The most common issue are string encodings, i.e. the input *byte arrays* **must** be identical (or your output won't be).

Comment: And, as we have already established, Rfc2898DeriveBytes *very likely* deploys UTF-8 encoding - so that would be identical.

Comment: @poupou Thanks for your input! Mono rocks! I created a flexible version of the Rfc2898DeriveBytes which takes an optional hashing algorithm:
`var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytesFlexible(passphrase, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), 50000, new HMACSHA256());`

It can be found on Github: https://github.com/Krumelur/XamarinBindings/blob/master/KS_PSPDFKit-Demo-Xamarin.iOS/Rfc2898DeriveBytesFlexible.cs